# How to go to a page from a UITableViewCell press.

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, swift, ibaction

I have a table with several cells and I would like to be able to make pages for each cell that can be accessed by clicking on them. I can't find any documentation on how to do this, but I assume its somewhere in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {


    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

I know this allows me to see what cell was pressed but I don't know where to go from here. Any help?

Comment: what type of page? Webpage?

Comment: @Rashad sorry I wasn't clear. This is for an iPhone app. I want to be able to go from pages within the app.

Comment: See my answer. You'll be needing the first option.

Answer (score 0):

The bellow example shows both opening a webpage in safari & moving to another page.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        Events *event = [[Events alloc] initWithNibName:@"Events" bundle:nil];
        event.parent = @"Guide";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:event animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.asdf.com"]];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Sorry if Im being confusing. What I'm trying to do is be able to click names that are in my table and it being me to a page with a description of that name essentially. Will this code help set that up?

Comment: You've to modify it according to your need. Its just an example. Like my Event class has a property named parent. As you can see I am setting that property by writing this event.parent = @"Guide";. When I move to event page I can check its parent. In this case it will be 'Guide'.

Comment: For your case I guess you need a class with some property like name, email, designation, description bla bla. and in your display class you can show these information. just pass the values to the display class and put the in view.

Comment: I still don't see the part that pushes the app to a new page upon the button press.

Comment: you didn't specify that you want to go to a different page by clicking a button in tableview cell. You just told that you want to move to a new page by clicking on the cell.

Comment: `Events *event = [[Events alloc] initWithNibName:@"Events" bundle:nil];` is the code that creates the 'page'. In this case it's a controller called Events that has an associated nib file. `[self.navigationController pushViewController:event animated:YES]` is the code that puts it up on the screen.